# Select data for 15 minute windows - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, histogram, window-functions

Right so I have a table such as this in PostgreSQL:

```
timestamp              duration

2013-04-03 15:44:58    4
2013-04-03 15:56:12    2
2013-04-03 16:13:17    9
2013-04-03 16:16:30    3
2013-04-03 16:29:52    1
2013-04-03 16:38:25    1
2013-04-03 16:41:37    9
2013-04-03 16:44:49    1
2013-04-03 17:01:07    9
2013-04-03 17:07:48    1
2013-04-03 17:11:00    2
2013-04-03 17:11:16    2
2013-04-03 17:15:17    1
2013-04-03 17:16:53    4
2013-04-03 17:20:37    9
2013-04-03 17:20:53    3
2013-04-03 17:25:48    3
2013-04-03 17:29:26    1
2013-04-03 17:32:38    9
2013-04-03 17:36:55    4
```

And I would like to get the following output:

timestampwindowstart = 2013-04-03 15:44:58

```
duration    count
1           0
2           1
3           0
4           1
9           0
```

timestampwindowstart = 2013-04-03 15:59:58

```
duration    count
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
9           1
```

timestampwindowstart = 2013-04-03 16:14:58

```
duration    count
1           1
2           0
3           1
4           0
9           0
```

timestampwindowstart = 2013-04-03 16:29:58

```
duration    count
1           2
2           0
3           0
4           0
9           1
```

etc...

So basically it cycles through the timestamps in 15 minute windows and outputs the distinct duration values along with their frequency (count). The timestampwindowstart value is the earliest timestamp for the window (i.e timestampwindowfinish = timestampwindowstart + 15 minutes)

This is so I can then plot the 15 minute interval histograms...

I have tried reading up but it is a bit complicated for me to get my head around and I don't have much time...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: OK, you do not have time, but expect others to invest their valuable time to solve your problem. The least you can do is to create an SQLfiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your data.

Comment: I said I don't have much time left and I have spent a long time already trying to get my head around this and I can't... As for the SQLfiddle demo, not everyone uses SQL fiddle, only a handful of people have helped me with SQL fiddle demos so I didn't think to create one, I will do it now, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bd2f6/21 I named my column `tstamp` instead of your `timestamp`

```
with t as (
  select
    generate_series(mitstamp,matstamp,'15 minutes') as int,
    duration
  from
    (select min(tstamp) mitstamp, max(tstamp) as matstamp from tmp) a,
    (select duration from tmp group by duration) b
)

select
  int as timestampwindowstart,
  t.duration,
  count(tmp.duration)
from
   t
   left join tmp on 
         (tmp.tstamp >= t.int and 
          tmp.tstamp < (t.int + interval '15 minutes') and 
          t.duration = tmp.duration)
group by
  int,
  t.duration
order by
  int,
  t.duration
```

Brief explanation:

1. Calculate minimum and maximum timestamp
2. Generate 15 minutes intervals between minimum and maximum
3. Cross join results with unique values of duration
4. Left join original data (left join is important, because this will keep all possible combination in output and there will be `null` where duration does not exists for given interval.
5. Aggregate data. `count(null)=0`

In case you have more tables and the algorithm should be applied on their union. Suppose we have three tables `tmp1, tmp2, tmp3` all with columns `tstamp` and `duration`. The we can extend the previous solution:

```
with 

tmpout as (
  select * from tmp1 union all
  select * from tmp2 union all
  select * from tmp3
)

,t as (
  select
    generate_series(mitstamp,matstamp,'15 minutes') as int,
    duration
  from
    (select min(tstamp) mitstamp, max(tstamp) as matstamp from tmpout) a,
    (select duration from tmpout group by duration) b
)

select
  int as timestampwindowstart,
  t.duration,
  count(tmp.duration)
from
   t
   left join tmpout on 
         (tmp.tstamp >= t.int and 
          tmp.tstamp < (t.int + interval '15 minutes') and 
          t.duration = tmp.duration)
group by
  int,
  t.duration
order by
  int,
  t.duration
```

You should really know `with` clause in PostgreSQL. It is invaluable concept for any data analysis in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you so much, would you be able to explain the code by any chance? I'm currently running the query and once it finishes I will accept this answer. The way I understand it you create a temporary table with a timestamp series generated by adding 15 minute intervals to the min timestamp, up to the max timestamp and also the duration grouped by distinct duration. You then select the timestamp interval, duration and frequency of the duration by performing a join to the temporary table and grouping and ordering by both the timestamp interval and duration...

Comment: Also sorry to add to the original question but how would I modify this code if I had three tables all with the same format and I wished to do the same thing but using the data from all three tables?

Comment: The answer shared by twn08 doesn't use temporary tables, but CTE's (Common Table Expressions), which can be found in the section of the docs at [WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).
If you want to use three tables you would probably UNION them together, see [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the way i'm thinking of using a union is to union the whole query with the same query on the second table, but wouldn't the 15 minute intervals get messed up? as for each table the last interval will stop at the last timestamp and not continue through to the first timestamp of the second table? And thanks for letting me know about CTE's!

Comment: "quick" ...? ;)