# Select a count of rows, order by dynamic ranges of time intervals in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, range, intervals

Here's the test table for my question :

```
CREATE TABLE document (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(120) NOT NULL,
    owner_id bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    doc_type_id smallint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    archived boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    insert_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    modify_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    last_writer_id bigint
);
```

Modify_date determines the last time someone edited a document.

In order to make some statistics, I need to get the time between the creation(insert_date) and modify_date. And then to display a bar chart, I need to get a count of document where this time interval is, for example, between 0 and 5 days, 6 and 10 days, etc. So ranges must be calculated in the query I guess. 
The result expected (or kind of...) is :

```
Age                Count
0-5                2
6-10               5
11-15              9
...                ...
```

Of course the age could be on a scale where 0-5 == 0, 6-10 == 1. I'll prepare the data to display them.

I found a post quite similar but I couldn't apply it to my case. ([Select data for 15 minute windows - PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516000/select-data-for-15-minute-windows-postgresql?rq=1))

Thanks for any answer you could bring to me.

EDIT 1:

The ranges needs to be dynamically generated from the minimum and maximum age I can get from the table.

Comment: In what way do you need dynamic generation? You must specify something more. E.g get min and change group every 5 days?

Comment: For example if the maximum age is 100, then I need ranges of 5 days from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with cte_ages as (
    select
        extract(day from (modify_date - insert_date))::int as age
    from document
), cte_groups as (
    select
        case when g.age = 1 then 0 else g.age end as gr_start,
        g.age + 4 as gr_end
    from generate_series(1, (select max(age) from cte_ages), 5) as g(age)
)
select
    g.gr_start::text || '-' || g.gr_end::text,
    count(a.age)
from cte_groups as g
    left outer join cte_ages as a on a.age between g.gr_start and g.gr_end
group by g.gr_start, g.gr_end
order by g.gr_start
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b7e8/27)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks a lot, first try, first blood :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i do not know postgres but if you can convert this to postgres, it will work:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM document
WHERE (TO_DAYS(modify_date) - TO_DAYS(insert_date)) < 11 
      AND (TO_DAYS(modify_date) - TO_DAYS(insert_date)) > 5
```

This query counts the number of documents modified between 6 and 10 days. But you have to run and modify the query to modify the range of days.

Comment: There is no `to_days()` function in Postgres

Comment: Thats why i said: "it you can convert this to postgres" :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (not the best performing!) is via a union:

```
select '0-5' as age, count(*) as count
from document where insert_date < [6 days])
union
select '6-10' as age, count(*) as count
from document where between insert_date [6 days] and [11 days])
```

Comment: Problem is, it's not dynamic range. I need this request to generate those ranges depending on the min & max age I can get from the table.