# Recognize maximum movement in quasi-variable time windows

Tags: sql, postgresql, machine-learning, time-series, window-functions

I table of have table (track_t, Postgresql 9.5) of timestamps and speed & distance measurements from soccer players.
The timestamps start before the game, roughly 30 minutes, and go up to 30 minutes after the game finishes. I have a query that can determine which 45 minute ranges have the most movement - avg(speed) and sum(distance) - and are therefore likely to be times where the game is being played.

```
SELECT
    tt.start_time
    , tt.game_id
    , tt.start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'CEST' + interval '45 minute' as end_time_lz
    , sum(aa.distance) as distance
    , avg(aa.speed) as speed
FROM
(
    SELECT
        game_id
        , GENERATE_SERIES(MIN(date_trunc('hour',ts)),max(date_trunc('minute',ts)),'1m') as start_time
    FROM track_t
        GROUP BY game_id
) tt
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        game_id
        , avg(speed) as speed
        , sum(distance) as distance
        , date_trunc('minute',ts) as timestamp
    FROM track_t
    GROUP BY 
        game_id
        , date_trunc('minute',ts)
) aa
ON aa.game_id = tt.game_id
AND aa.timestamp >= tt.start_time 
AND aa.timestamp < tt.start_time + interval '45 minute'

GROUP BY
    tt.start_time
    , tt.game_id

ORDER BY
    SUM(aa.distance) desc
    , AVG(aa.speed) desc
;
```

The first part creates all the 45 minute windows with the [GENERATE_SERIES()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516664/2327328) function, based on each minute of timestamp. So if the game started at 10:00, and the data starts at 09:30, then I create 45 minute windows on 09:30, 09:31, 09:32, etc.

The second part calculates the average speed and total distance for that 45 minute window.

Then, to determine which 45 minute window is the most likely, I can sort by sum(distance) and avg(speed) to give me the start time.

The results look like this (limit 10 ordered rows)

```
start_time; game_id; end_time; sum(distance); avg(speed)
*"2016-09-03 17:03:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 17:48:00";47935.0703622001;1.06124213271675*
"2016-09-03 17:04:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 17:49:00";47761.7538393264;1.0572395112247
"2016-09-03 17:02:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 17:47:00";47642.3581425403;1.05482864669178
"2016-09-03 17:05:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 17:50:00";46949.1297795754;1.03702742158256
"2016-09-03 17:01:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 17:46:00";46868.0351728161;1.03604043683709
*"2016-09-03 17:58:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 18:43:00";46481.3160240327;1.03470232279402*
"2016-09-03 17:00:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 17:45:00";46454.0167265013;1.02557019844115
"2016-09-03 17:59:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 18:44:00";46183.0355093333;1.02985443158215
"2016-09-03 17:57:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 18:42:00";46059.2319184038;1.02059235291926
"2016-09-03 18:00:00";"a20160903";"2016-09-03 18:45:00";45984.1387791433;1.02661395680708
```

and the two likely start times for each half are marked with * (e.g. 17:03 and 17:58).

That works fine to create a sortable list, but **how can I automatically select the 1st and 2nd half start times?**

Additionally, a half-time of play is usually more than 45 minutes, due to injury time, which can be between 0 and 5+ minutes per half. **How can I automatically scan time-windows that include possible injury time, and are between 45 and 50 minutes, and select the "maximum movement window" from these combinations?**

If you plot start_time on the x axis, and sum(distance) on the y axis, you see a nice bimodal distrubition- so I was thinking some analytical function for recognizing half-start-time as well as injury time.

[image: bimodal distribution]

(the hours don't match the data above due to UTC/local time transformation)

---

Note: I would prefer to do this with SQL (Postgres 9.5), but I do have a python wrapper that I can use, which may give more machine-learning libraries.

Comment: Use the second derivative? (acceleration) (or maybe just use a treshold // window comparator would do, too)

Comment: How many rows exist for each minute? When you plot the individual rows of the `aa` Derived Table you should see that during the play activity is high and low before/after. What about using `LAG`/`LEAD` to check for this?

Comment: @dnoeth I have 200 millisecond resolution, so in total 300 timestamps per minute per player. I aggregate to minute in order to drown out noise. Good idea for LEAD/LAG.